# Trazer todos os resultados necessários em uma query - MariaDB

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

Preciso reformular um pequeno sistema, que hoje, funciona mas abrindo várias conexões com o banco de dados, e quando há muitos registros, o banco de dados cai, ou quando isso não acontece, a página fica muito lenta.

Então, para contornar esse problema, estou elaborando uma query que me traga todos os resultados de uma vez só, e ai eu trato essas informações do lado PHP para melhorar o desempenho.

Só estou tendo um pequeno problema: a tabela, que chamarei de teste, pode ter múltiplas relações com teste2 ou teste3, então criei uma tabela item_teste para relaciona-las, porém as informações da tabela teste2 se repetem quando executo a query.

Segue um exemplo no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c8ee2/3)

Esta é a query que estou usando:

```
select distinct t1.teste, 
GROUP_CONCAT(t2.teste2 SEPARATOR '&') teste2 ,
GROUP_CONCAT(t3.teste3 SEPARATOR '&') teste3 
FROM item_teste it
join teste t1 on t1.id_teste = it.id_teste
join teste2 t2 on t2.id_teste2 = it.id_teste2
join teste3 t3 on t3.id_teste3 = it.id_teste3
where t1.teste like '%testando%'
group by t1.id_teste;
```

Não sei se essa é a melhor maneira de otimizar, então, há alguma outra forma de otimizar as consultas ou estou no caminho certo?

Answer (score 1):

Para não repetir as informações do teste2 (não testei mas acredito que resolva) acrescente `distinct` ex: `group_concat(distinct t2.teste2 SEPARATOR '&')`